# Error fetching data for metricset kafka.partition

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, metricbeat

I have ssl kafka service on aks cluster and I want to get metrics with MetricBeat, index it with ElasticSearch and display with Kibana.

My kafka is set as :

```
helm install dp bitnami/kafka \
            --set replicaCount=1 \
            --set rbac.create=true \
            --set externalAccess.enabled=true \
            --set externalAccess.autoDiscovery.enabled=true \
            --set auth.clientProtocol=tls \
            --set auth.interBrokerProtocol=tls \
            --set "auth.tls.existingSecrets[0]=dp-ume-kafka-secrets-0" \
            --set auth.tls.password=$PASSWORD -n sslkafka
```

and in metricbeat and i am enabling its module as -

```
- module: kafka
        enabled: true
        metricsets:
          - partition
          - consumergroup
        period: 10s
        hosts: ["<kafka-IP>:9094"]
```

But i am getting below error from metricbeat pod -

```
Error fetching data for metricset kafka.consumergroup: error in connect: getting cluster client for advertised broker with address <kafka-IP>:9094: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)

Error fetching data for metricset kafka.partition: error in connect: getting cluster client for advertised broker with address <kafka-IP>:9094: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: can your metricbeat server establish a connection to kafka broker on port 9094? try ´telnet kafkaip 9094´ on your metricbeat server.

Comment: no its not. i guess because kafka is ssl enabled.

The kubernetes secret used above is created using jks files(truststore and keystore).
and uploaded to github env. I am downloading this jks files from there. but not sure, how to mount it so that can be used in metricbeat

Comment: if `telnet kafkaip 9094` can't establish a connection, that means your metricbeat server can't access the kafka server via this port. at this point it shouldn't have something to do with ssl. check for firewall rules or port forwarding.